# How to display instagram API response in javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, instagram

I am trying to send a delete request to instagram api using ajax but my current javascript code display the response in alert box as:

```
 <pre></pre><pre></pre>
```

so i cant find the problem why delete request is not successful! if i call the same php script(doit.php) from the browser and pass it media id then the delete will be successful!

could any one tell me what is wrong with my current delete ajax request that fails to make delete request to instagram api?

[Instagram API Docs for Deleting Like](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/#delete_likes)

sample api response:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    }, 
    "data": null
}
```

javascript:

```
<script>
function deleteLike(a,b)
{
alert("MediaID:"+a+"\nId:"+b);

 var url = "./doit.php";
    $.post(url, {
        "method": "post",
      //"method": "delete",
        "MediaID": a, 
    }, function(data) 
       {
         var ajaxResponse = data;

          alert("Response:"+ajaxResponse);

          if (data.meta.code == 200) {
             alert("sucessDelete");


            }

    })

}
</script>
```

PHP CODE:

```
$MediaIDvar= $_POST["MediaID"];
//$MediaIDvar= $_GET["MediaID"];

$url2 = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/".$MediaIDvar."/likes?xxxxx";
        $api_response2 = get_data2(''.$url2);
        $record2 = json_decode($api_response2); // JSON decode 



echo '<pre>' . print_r($api_response2, true) . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' . print_r($record2, true) . '</pre>';
// to see what is in the $api_response and $record object



/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data2($url2) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Use `console.log(data);` and the chrome inspector or Firebug for Firefox.

Comment: in firebug i get <pre></pre><pre></pre> as response back! why when i call the php from browser it works find and give me correct response but when i call it from ajax i get <pre></pre><pre></pre> and delete fails ?

Answer (score 0):

$MediaIDvar= $_POST["MediaID"];

$MediaIDvar= $_GET["MediaID"]; // => this will overwrite the previous $MediaIDvar

it will work if you call the php script with a GET variable, not through ajax using POST ;-)

Comment: thanks for reply . i tried it without $MediaIDvar= $_GET["MediaID"] and still no response ! api response is kind of xml i think . so you think my way of display response is correct ? if delete was sussffule i should get code:200 as  response ! but now i get <pre></pre><pre></pre> for both echo of my api response!